# Can I enter the US if I have been to Iran?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens, iran

I’m a British citizen of Iranian heritage, and me and my parents visit Iran every year. I’m hoping to go to New York for a trip, however my Iranian dad (a British citizen) once applied for a visa, and got rejected.

It’s my first time dealing with travelling this complicated, and I’m not getting any straight answers from the internet. I would very much appreciate it if someone could tell me if I need a visa, and if I do, am I likely to get rejected if I apply? Is there anything else I need to sign up or fill in forms for? Thanks very much for any answers.

If it helps, I’m a student who’s trying to go on a school trip, and our school is using a travel agency to arrange it.

Comment: @user77409 Nikki is not eligible to travel under the Visa Waiver Program because he has been in Iran after 2011 (see the Terrorist Travel Prevention Act, 2015). Unless there is some other important situation not mentioned, like Canadian citizenship, a visa is required.

Comment: @Calchas Thanks for the correction, I deleted my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: The UK government’s travel advice for UK citizens planning to travel to the USA is a good place to start https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa/entry-requirements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that you have visited Iran within the past 5 years, you are not eligible to enter the US using the Visa Waiver Program (VWP).  If you attempt to obtain an ESTA (which is required in order to travel under the VWP), then your application will be rejected based on you answering Yes to the question regarding visiting Iran.

However, you are eligible to apply for a US Visitor Visa (B2).

Whether your visa application is approved or not will be at the discretion of the consulate staff, and the exact criteria they use are not made public so there's no way to really know in advance whether your particular application will be approved or not - the only way to find out is to apply.

Presuming you live in the UK, and have a valid reason for your regular trips to Iran, then it's probably likely your visa will be approved - but again it's not possible to say that with any real certainty.